# Debug Django app on Heroku

Tags: django, debugging, heroku, remote-debugging, pdb

How can I debug django app deployed on Heroku. I can not reproduce the issue on local setup and want to drop to pdb in handling request code. Is there a way to connect to the web dyno and step thru the code handling request.

Please suggest if there is any alternate way was well. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

you can access your project on heroku using

```
 heroku run bash
```

then from there you can run any django command

Answer (score 0):

On your local machine navigate to project root directory and run

`heroku run your_command`

Comment: Thanks!! I want to attach to the running process on heroku. heroku run will let me run some script or management command

Comment: What do you want to attach? I may not getting it right

Comment: I want to attach to the app running on heroku from my local dev server. Remote pdb?